# get values using regular expression and preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have string data

```
$pages = "mangaName=&authorArtist=asdas123s&genres=sn&genres[23]=on&genres[29]=on&status=&chrome=&submit=+";

function get_h1($file){
    $h1tags = preg_match_all('/\[(\w*)\]/is',$file,$patterns);
    $res = array();
    array_push($res,$patterns[2]);
    array_push($res,count($patterns[2]));
    return $res;
}
```

i want get number on genres[23] , genres[29]

`[0] => 23
 [1] => 29`

Comment: How about http://php.net/parse_str ?

Comment: `i want get number on genres[23] , genres[29]`. I did't quite understand. Could you rephrase?

Answer (score 1):

```
$pages = "mangaName=&authorArtist=asdas123s&genres=sn&genres[23]=on&genres[29]=on&status=&chrome=&submit=+";

parse_str($pages, $parsed);

var_dump(array_keys($parsed['genres'])); // array(2) { [0]=> int(23) [1]=> int(29) }
```

Answer (score 0):

zerkms' answer is the right one, but if you really want to use regexp, change yours with this one:

```
preg_match_all('/\[(\w*?)\]/is',$file,$patterns);
 note the non-greedy __^
```